# CircleCI 2.1 : Cannot find a definition for command named process_env_vars

Tags: circleci

My `config.yml` looks like below:

```yaml
parameters:
  ENV_TYPE:
    type: string
    default: "main"
  TAGS:
    type: string
    default: "default"
  REGION:
    type: string
    default: "eu-west-1"
jobs:
 network-egress-orbs:
    parameters:
      check_mode:
        type: string
        default: "check_mode=yes"
    circleci_ip_ranges: true
    docker:
      - image: xxxxxx
        aws_auth:
          aws_access_key_id: $access_key
          aws_secret_access_key: $secret_key
    steps:
      - checkout
      - ansible-tf/execute_playbook:
          app_parent: 'network'
          app_name: 'egress'
          tags: "<< pipeline.parameters.TAGS >>"
          aws_region: '"<< pipeline.parameters.REGION >>"'
          ansible_version: '2.8.0'
          tf_version: '0.12.30'
          ansible_extra_vars: "<< parameters.check_mode >>"
          branch_to_env_map: 'feature/ nonprod\nmaster prod'
          no_output_timeout: "45m"
      - process_env_vars:
          env_type: '"<< pipeline.parameters.ENV_TYPE >>"'
```

I basically want to read the parameter `ENV_TYPE` so I can use it later in my ansible code. When running this pipeline, getting the error `Cannot find a definition for command named process_env_vars`. I double-checked the indentation as well.

How can I get this working? Or is there any other way to read that variable in `config.yml`?